# The best way to merge beta and live Sharepoint systems

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am currently using sharepoint to develop an intranet system for my company

We currently have 1 (Uat/ beta) server and 1 (live) server

I am looking for the most elegent way to update the live server with the changes that have been made to the beta server

Normally this is not a problem with a standard website, but SharePoint is a horror to work with, so anyone with any experience in this

your advice is most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Their is OOTB way to merge the data between the SharePoint environment. This is depend the changes you need to move.

- If you want to move the content then you have only option is use the 3rd party tool.
- if you want overwrite the production site then you can use Backup and restore Or move the content database Options. But in this way you will lost all our production data and overwrite it by UAT.
  this is not really recommended, if you have live production data.
- Another way is manually move the changes to production using the SharePoint designer but it depend upon your changes.
- For empty or small sites, using site template can meet the
  requirement, you can consider using this.
- For kinds of changes move, there are various ways to sync the conent,
  like lists, master pages, css, etc. should be packaged in solution
  file, and deploy it between them. Please find related information
  from following article:

[SharePoint 2010: Copy production content to acceptance/test environment:](http://www.appdelivery.com/2012/09/sharepoint-2010-copy-production-content-to-acceptancetest-environment/)

[SharePoint 2013 Dev/Test/Production environment – Moving content:](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78483/sharepoint-2013-dev-test-production-environment-moving-content)

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a3dc4a4-2561-4456-a5b2-a10766fae513/can-i-merge-a-site-from-preproduction-with-the-content-already-in-production-alm-query?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)